# Protobuf 3 : graphical (GUI) tool for seriliazation and deserialization

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm looking for a tool that generates and read easily Protobuf data.

This tool should read a Protofile, and then presents a way to fill fields in order to serialize a message in Protobuf.

Added to that, if it can perform deserialization too, it would be very interesting for testing protobuf exchanges, during development.

(to be honest; Postman does not support protobuf message edition).

Does someone know a tool like this ?

Answer (score 4):

could http://protobufeditor.sourceforge.net/ fit your need?

Looking at the discussions, it should support proto3.
https://sourceforge.net/p/protobufeditor/discussion/general/thread/a034177f/

Let us know if it is a good solution for you!